# Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series drivers for ubuntu

Tags: dell, amd-graphics, ubuntu-drivers

Where can I find and how can I install the latest graphic drivers for Dell Inspiron 5520?I`m using 16.04 LTS Ubuntu Gnome.

When I use  `sudo apt-get install fglrx` this appears

[image: This appears]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install binary drivers is to use the built in `Additional Drivers` manager in Ubuntu.

Select the `fglrx(proprietary)` and click apply changes(*You might need to enter your password*).

[image: AMD Drivers]

After the fglrx driver is installed, reboot your system and login. To check whether the fglrx driver is working, open a terminal and type:

```
fglrxinfo
```

You should see an output similar to:

```
fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series       
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11399 Compatibility Profile Context
```

You can also install the drivers by typing this into the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Once that finishes installing, make sure to generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING.

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

After that, reboot and check that the drivers have installed by opening the terminal and typing `fglrxinfo`. You should see an output similar to the above.

A detailed guide to install drivers at over at the [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) website. Have a read of this if you need to be extra sure.

Comment: I edited question,problem runing sudo apt-get install fglrx

Comment: This does not apply to 16.04, see the answer to the duplicate question.